# No mappable values found when using RKXMLReaderSerialization

Tags: ios, xml, core-data, restkit-0.20

I have an iOS app using Restkit 0.20.1 along with RKXMLReaderSerialization 0.20.0 to pull xml formatted data from a server.  The code works great if the server sends me JSON data but now that I am attempting to pull the data in XML format I have hit a dead end.  I am still receiving the data from the server but I get an error that reads:

```
restkit.object_mapping:RKMapperOperation.m:98 Adding mapping error: No mappable values found for any of the attributes or relationship mappings
```

I am assuming this means that the object mapper does not recognize any of the data as a match for my core data attributes so there is nothing to map.  I installed RKXMLReaderSerialization via cocoapods and registered the class according to the documentation.  But obviously I am missing something.  Can anyone point it out?

Here is where I register the serialization class

```
// Set the default store shared instance
    [RKManagedObjectStore setDefaultStore:managedObjectStore];

    RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.myserver.com"]];
    [RKMIMETypeSerialization registerClass:[RKXMLReaderSerialization class] forMIMEType:@"application/xml"];
```

Here is the mapping and response descriptor portion:

```
RKEntityMapping *entityMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Gist" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
    [entityMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
     @"articleId":      @"gistID",
     @"title":          @"title",
     @"hashtags":       @"hashtags",
     @"imageUrl":       @"imageUrl",
     @"summary":        @"summary"}];
    entityMapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"gistID" ];
RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:entityMapping pathPattern:@"/rest/article/getTicker" keyPath:nil statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
```

Here is the applicable piece of the log:

```
restkit.object_mapping:RKMapperOperation.m:98 Adding mapping error: No mappable values    found for any of the attributes or relationship mappings
restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:241 GET 'http://www.myserver.com/rest/article/getTicker?ip=255.255.255.0' (200 OK / 0 objects) [request=0.2420s mapping=0.0151s total=0.2737s]:
    response.headers={
        Connection = "Keep-Alive";
        "Content-Type" = "application/xml";
        Date = "Fri, 31 May 2013 04:30:50 GMT";
        "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=5, max=100";
        "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
    }
    response.body=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><tickers><ticker><articleId>7587</articleId><authorId>10</authorId><authorName>AFP  </authorName><city>Kabul</city><copyrightLine>Copyright 2012 AFP</copyrightLine><countryCode>US</countryCode><countryName>AF</countryName><hashTags>#Afghanistan #unrest #art #offbeat </hashTags><imageUrl>http://www.mywebsite.com/services/images/AFP/photo_1369471279196-2-2.jpg</imageUrl><latitude>34.52813</latitude><longitude>69.17233</longitude>
```

As you can see the response body comes in as XML with the core data attributes I am looking for (articleId, title, hashtags,...) but it must not be running the body thru the xmlreader....  I'm pretty new to iOS and Objective-C so any help is appreciated and snippets are worth their weight in gold!
Thanks

**Update...** 
Here is how the xml comes from the server

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tickers>
    <ticker>
        <articleId>7587</articleId>
        <authorId>10</authorId>
        <authorName>AFP </authorName>
        <city>Kabul</city>
        <copyrightLine>Copyright 2012 AFP</copyrightLine>
        <countryCode>US</countryCode>
        <countryName>AF</countryName>
        <hashTags>#Afghanistan #unrest #art #offbeat </hashTags>
        <imageUrl>http://www.mywebsite.com/services/images/AFP/photo_1369471279196-2-2.jpg</imageUrl>
        <latitude>34.52813</latitude>
        <longitude>69.17233</longitude>
        <title>Day after Kabul attacks, 10,000 peace balloons</title>
        <totComments>0</totComments>
        <totDislikes>0</totDislikes>
        <totInappropriate>0</totInappropriate>
        <totLikes>0</totLikes>
        <totViews>0</totViews>
    </ticker>
```

**UPDATE #2....**
Here is the difference is how the response is mapped when I receive XML vs. receiving JSON from the server.

Serialization

```
tickers =     {
    ticker =         (
                    {
            articleId =                 {
                text = 7587;
            };
            authorId =                 {
                text = 10;
            };
            authorName =                 {
                text = AFP;
            };
            city =                 {
                text = Kabul;
            };
            copyrightLine =                 {
                text = "Copyright 2012 AFP";
            };
           .....Goes on like this for each attribute
```

JSON direct from server

```
    {
    articleId = 7587;
    authorId = 10;
    authorName = "AFP  ";
    city = Kabul;
    copyrightLine = "Copyright 2012 AFP";
    countryCode = US;
    countryName = AF;
    hashTags = "#Afghanistan #unrest #art #offbeat ";
    imageUrl = "http://www.mywebsite.com/services/images/AFP/photo_1369471279196-2-2.jpg";
    latitude = "34.52813";
    longitude = "69.17233";
    title = "Day after Kabul attacks, 10,000 peace balloons";
    totComments = 0;
    totDislikes = 0;
    totInappropriate = 0;
    totLikes = 0;
    totViews = 0;
},
```

Anyone have an idea how to address this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the serialisation is probably fine. I think the problem is that the mapping doesn't have enough information to navigate the XML (which I assume has more tags than the corresponding JSON).

Try telling the response descriptor the keypath of the location of the data in the XML:

```
RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:entityMapping pathPattern:@"/rest/article/getTicker" keyPath:@"tickers.ticker" statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
```

Update: does your mapping need to be:

```
[entityMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
 @"articleId.text":      @"gistID",
 @"title.text":          @"title",
 @"hashtags.text":       @"hashtags",
 @"imageUrl.text":       @"imageUrl",
 @"summary.text":        @"summary"}];
```

Comment: Wain, This is definitely getting me somewhere.  With your suggestion the console now reads [NSDictionaryM length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance....

Comment: Just figured that out.  It was occurring when the code was trying to load the string for imageUrl into a URL.  I commented that out and added some logging and it appears that the mapping still isn't right.  I am recieving 10 individual articleID's but the count only shows 1.  Also when I log the string received from "title" there is no text attributed.  You are definitely getting the checkmark for your answer I just have a few other things to work out!

Comment: Try turning on trace logging: RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/ObjectMapping", RKLogLevelTrace);

Comment: Wow, I was using "Restkit/Network", RKLogLevelTrace, Thanks for the pointer on that!  I'm still plugging away..  Be back soon with an update!

Comment: Added a few updates to show how the object mapper is handling the xml data

Comment: Got it!  Thanks Wain you were spot on!  The only other modification I needed to make was to my entityMapping.  I just had to change "articleId" to "articleId.text" due to the way the xml was being mapped.  Couldn't have done it without your snippet and pointer about the trace logging!